# polymer - data binding to variables in behavior

Tags: templates, data-binding, polymer, bind, behavior

My problem is that my polymer components don't appear to be data bound to the variables defined in my behavior.  Would like to know if this is not supported or what my flawed thinking is.

I have shared variables in my behavior used as kind of a global state to anyone using the behavior:

```
<script>
var StackOverflowBehavior = {
    properties: {
        show: {
            type: Boolean,
            value: false,
            notify: true
        }
    },
    attached: function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://myRestApiURL',
            success: this.onRequestSucceed,
            error: this.onRequestFailed
        });
    },

   onRequestSucceed: function(response) {
        this.show = true; // i hardcoded this at the moment to make sure it changes.  console logging shows that the variable is getting changed.  also tried changing this to this.show
   }
```

Now I hook up my polymer component to the behavior:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{show}}">
    <!-- SOME ELEMENTS HERE -->
</template>

Polymer({
   is: "my-polymer-component",
   behaviors: [
      StackOverflowBehavior
   ],
```

The problem is that initially, the template bound to the show variable is bound to the initial StackOverflowBehavior.show so the template is invisible, but the template doesn't appear when show turns true.  Similarly, when I initialize show=true in StackOverflowBehavior, it starts out visible but when I set show = false, the template does not disappear as I would expect.

I did do a workaround, which is to use iron-signal to publish that the show variable changed.  Then each polymer component has a local show variable that is set to the new show variable when it receives the signal.  Each polymer component's template is bound to its local variable.  This DOES work.  However, when bound to the shared variable in the behavior it doesnt work.

Edit: It seems like if I change update the variable from the attached function, the data binding to the shared global behavior works but if I change the variable from a user-defined function it doesn't.  From the polymer component with the data-bound template, I can call console.log(show) from within the ready() method and have it  print out the correct value.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this JS Bin similar to your code? http://jsbin.com/totoma/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @TomaszPluskiewicz it is similar, but the Behavior has some ajax call in ready() and the method that handles the callback is a user-defined function in the behavior.

Comment: Change the value of `this.show` instead of `show` and make sure your `attached` and `onRequestSucceed` are outside `properties` object.

Comment: thanks, but my error was totally unrelated (see my answer post)...sorry guys and thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

sigh...actual code takes the json response in the ajax and tries to convert it to boolean, but it's actually a string (isn't my api that does this) so I get conversion errors which screw up the data binding.